# How to fix: "Social Media Sprites not Displaying Correctly in Portrait Mode"

Tags: html, css

My real estate team is integrating our database into a new CRM system and  our email signatures are not mobile responsive. In landscape mode the social media sprites display correctly. The tables stack correctly when in portrait mode but the sprites are stretched to the width of the container.

We hired an outside group to develop the system, we cannot modify the CSS code just the HTML source code on the signatures. Is there any fix we can do to the HTML or one we can suggest to the developers to make the look consistent? I am the most computer literate in the office and was given the task of finding an answer.

Thanks to [Munni's help below](https://jsfiddle.net/jhqdbeog/3/), the images are at least clear but HUGE. We are now a little closer to what would make sense on a mobile display. See the subsequent image for the result.

[Full Source Code](https://github.com/PHXRealtor/EmailSignature_Fail/blob/master/Signature_source_Code)

[image: problem image]
[[image: Problem image 2]

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/css/wsc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body aria-readonly="false">
<p>&nbsp;</p>`

<div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0px;max-width: 680px;min-width: 200px;background: #fff;text-align: left;">
<div class="email-container" style="background: white;font-family: sans-serif;margin: 0 auto;overflow: hidden;">
<div class="accentline" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 28px;font-weight: 400;color: #fff;line-height: .33;text-align: center;margin-bottom: 0px;background: black;">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="accentlinediamond" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 28px;line-height: .75;text-align: center;margin-bottom: 5px;width: 200px;background: #fff;margin-left: 0;color:#93f542;">▼</div>

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="row" style="padding: 0px;" width="100%">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="deviceWidth" style="padding-right: 10px; width: 150px;"><a class="userphoto" href="http://www.realvolve.com" style="width: 150px;text-align: center;"><img alt="" class="unique-inline-img-class" dir="" document_id="337728" id="" lang="" longdesc="" src="https://realvolve-production.s3.amazonaws.com/message_templates/879660270d928312088b/Headshot_5.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; float: right;" title="" /></a></td>
                        <td class="deviceWidth" style="padding: 0px;">
                        <div class="signature-name" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 26px;font-weight: 600;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-align: left;margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 2px;"><span style="font-size:16px;">[[CurrentUser#FirstName]] [[CurrentUser#LastName]]</span></div>

                        <div class="signature-team" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">[[TeamName]]</div>

                        <div class="signature-company" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">[[CurrentUser#Company]]</div>

                        <div class="signature-phone" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">c: [[CurrentUser#CellPhone]]</div>

                        <div class="signature-phone" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">o: [[CurrentUser#WorkPhone]]</div>

                        <div class="signature-link" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-decoration: none;text-decoration-color: dodgerblue;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;"><a class="signature-link" href="mailto:[[CurrentUser#EmailAddress]]" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-decoration: none;text-decoration-color: dodgerblue;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">[[CurrentUser#EmailAddress]]</a></div>

                        <div class="signature-link" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-decoration: none;text-decoration-color: dodgerblue;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;"><a class="signature-link" href="[[CurrentUser#Website]]" style="margin: 0px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;color: #000;line-height: 1.00;text-decoration: none;text-decoration-color: dodgerblue;text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">[[CurrentUser#Website]]</a></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<!––Part of source code that houses the social media sprites, not sure if other code effects the display properties––>
                    <tr>
<td class="deviceWidth" colspan="2" style="padding-right: 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ParkerPHXRealEstate/" target="_blank"><img border="0" height="32" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/realvolve-public/template-photos/facebook.png" style="max-height: 32px;max-width: 32px" width="32" /></a>

&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img border="0" height="32" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/realvolve-public/template-photos/youtube.png" style="max-height: 32px;max-width: 32px" width="32" /></a>

<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/parkerw" target="_blank"><img border="0" height="32" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/realvolve-public/template-photos/linkedin.png" style="max-height: 32px;max-width: 32px" width="100%" /></a>

&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/houses_and_bikes" target="_blank"><img border="0" height="32" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/realvolve-public/template-photos/instagram.png" style="max-height: 32px;max-width: 32px" width="100%" />

</a>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

We want the social media icons to display correctly on portrait or landscape mode. See Image for visual of problem. Is there anything we can change in the code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put exact `height` and `width` instead of `max-height` and `max-height` in the social media image. I have modified your code here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/jhqdbeog/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I uploaded the result above. Our sales rep says that the dev team we are working with hasn'tt implemented mobile responsiveness on the back end yet. I think the rep is just talking without asking.